# ANDROID SQLITE: How to retrieve primary key of a certain row

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Pretty simple question, but I still did not find my answer around the internet:
Basically I just finished creating a new row and inserted it into the database, but I want to save the newly created primary key of that row. How do I access it?
As it stands, I am trying to use the rest of the column's values to find a certain row, but I am getting the SQLiteException : bind or column index out of range.

Here is the code for my current function trying to get the keyid:

```
        public String getPrimaryKey(String gameTitle, String gameType, String calories, String hours, String minutes) {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null,new String[]{gameTitle, gameType,calories, hours, minutes},null, null,null,null);

        if(cursor.getCount()<1)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "????";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String keyid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
        cursor.close();
        return keyid;

    }
```

The strings being passed in the parameters are the other columns that I am trying to use to access the primary key.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216790/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-last-inserted-id-using-sqlite-from-java) will give you what you sort of need to get the last insert ID.

Unfortunately, according to http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html:

> If a separate thread performs a new INSERT on the same database connection while the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() function is running and thus changes the last insert rowid, then the value returned by sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() is unpredictable and might not equal either the old or the new last insert rowid.

Therefore, grabbing the last row ID is susceptible to concurrency issues.

You may want to consider generating the primary key yourself instead of automatically generating it.

Alternatively, if there is some other field/fields you can search for that uniquely identify the row, you can select based on that -- however, in that case, those other field(s) should really be the actual primary key.

Answer (score 1):

> ANDROID SQLITE: How to retrieve primary key of a certain row

How you actually doing it:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
}
```

You need to check whether your Cursor is empty or not. In your actual code you're calling it but don't check returned value.

Another approach how to get rowId is if you're inserting rows via build-in method `insert()` it returns rowId of newly inserted row.

```
long rowId = db.insert("table", "nullColumnHack", data);
```

---

Also you passed as selection null which means:

> Passing null will return all rows for the given table.

and then you are passing to selectionArgs five values which don't match with number of columns in selection (you passed null there). They have to match. So you need to fix it:

- Add columns (same count as in selectionArgs) to selection
- Pass null also to selectionArgs