# Sqlite does not return correct primarykey in php

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I am creating a movie database for a school project, and im trying to add 2 values to a many to many relation in sqlite. However, for some reason the second query does not return the primarykey of the newly added movie, but always a 1. I have tested the queries with sql, and then they returned the values like normal, so I dont think theres something wrong with the sql queries.

```
public function add_movie($title, $genre, $actor, $director, $agecategory, $warning){   
        $query1 = $this->db->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO movie
            (title, agecategorynumber) VALUES (?,?);"
        );
        $query1->bindValue(1, $title);
        $query1->bindValue(2, $agecategory);

        try{
            $query1->execute();         
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        $query2 = $this->db->prepare(
            "SELECT movie.movienumber
            FROM movie
            WHERE movie.title LIKE ?"
        );
        $query2->bindValue(1, $title);

        try{
            $titlenumber = $query2->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   

        $query3 = $this->db->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO movieactor
            (movienumber, actornumber) VALUES (?,?);"
        );
        $query3->bindValue(1,$titlenumber);
        $query3->bindValue(2,$actor);

        try{
            $query3->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

Comment: If you want the auto-increment id of the last record that was inserted, then don’t try nonsense such as shown above, but do it the _right_ way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216790/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-last-inserted-id-using-sqlite-from-java

Comment: @CBroe your link is for Java/JDBC while this question is for PHP.

Comment: @timclutton one of the answers mentions `last_insert_rowid()`. Duplicate does not have to mean “copy & paste-ready answer” to me, a reasonable effort to find the relevant piece of information can be expected IMHO. (Specifically in such a case with only two, rather short and concise answers. I would agree to your point if this was one of the questions that had dozens of answers all saying different things already.)

Comment: @CBroe Agreed.  In this case it's a bit misleading, though, as PDO provides a native method to do this: [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).